# Find longest word in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm working on this codility coding challenge and I cannot get the code to work for all inputs, particularly large ones. The rules for this are [here](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/90-tasks_from_indeed_prime_2015_challenge/longest_password/).

To summarize, I need each word in the string to be tested for: alpha-numeric characters only, even number of letters, and odd number of digits.

For the sample input - "test 5 a0A pass007 ?xy1", this solution effectively ignores "test" (it has an even number of digits, 0 digits) and "?xy1" (special character, ?). From the leftover options, it chooses pass007 as the longest word and returns 7 (length of word).

I start by splitting the string into separate words and then generating if statements to check if each word in my new array meets the requirements, isAlpha, isAlphaEven (remainder 0 for even # of letters), isNumeric (remainder 1 for odd numbers).

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks much! :)

```
 // you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, 
 // e.g. console.log('this is a debug message');

function solution(S) {
// write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, 
// e.g. console.log('this is a debug message');
// write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
var words = S.split(" "); 
var isAlpha = /^[0-9a-zA-z]*$/; 
var isAlphaEven = /^[a-zA-Z]/;
var isNumeric = /^[0-9]/; 
var maxLength = -1;

for(var i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) { 
    if(words[i].match(isAlpha) 
    && words[i].replace(isAlphaEven, '').length % 2 == 0
    && words[i].replace(isNumeric, '').length % 2 == 1
    || words[i].match(isNumeric)
    ) {
        maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, words[i].length);
        //console.log(words[i], maxLength);
    }
}

 return maxLength; 
}
```

Comment: `isAlphaEven` and `isNumeric` only match the first character of the string.

Comment: When you replace `isAlphaEven` with an empty string, you're getting the length of all the characters that *don't* match it, not the number of alpha characters.

Comment: You can't really use regular expression to check that the length is a multiple of two, merely that there is at *least* two.

Comment: You can get the number of alpha characters with `alpha = words[i].match(/[a-z]/gi); numAlpha = alpha ? alpha.length : 0;`. The variable is needed because `match()` returns `null` if there are no matches rather than an empty array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that the patterns

```
var isAlphaEven = /^[a-zA-Z]/;
var isNumeric = /^[0-9]/;
```

can only match characters at the start of the string: `^` anchors to the beginning. It also isn't a global match, so it'll only replace one character. Another problem is that you're *replacing* the matches with the empty string, rather than testing the number of matches. To test the number of matches, use `.match` instead, with the global flag, and check the length of the resulting array (or null if there are no matches):

```js
function solution(S) {
  // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
  // you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, 
  // e.g. console.log('this is a debug message');
  // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
  var words = S.split(" ");
  var allAlphaNumeric = /^[\da-z]*$/i;
  var alpha = /[a-z]/gi;
  var numeric = /\d/g;
  var maxLength = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
    if (words[i].match(allAlphaNumeric) &&
      (words[i].match(alpha) || []).length % 2 == 0 &&
      (words[i].match(numeric) || []).length % 2 == 1
    ) {
      maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, words[i].length);
    }
  }

  return maxLength;
}

console.log(solution("test 5 a0A pass007 ?xy1"));
```

Note that you can use the case-insensitive flag instead of repeating `a-zA-Z`, and you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` if you wish.

While you could use `.replace` to figure out the number of matches, it'd be convoluted: you'd have to replace everything that *doesn't* match with the empty string, which would make the code's intent somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766110/402037) why your approach didn't work as expected.
So I thought I could add a slightly different approach with multiple `.filter()` steps

```js
function findLongestWord(input) {
  const isAlphaNumericOnly = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
  const numbersOnly = /\d/g;
  const alphaOnly = /[a-z]/gi;
  
  const validWords = input.split(/\s/)
                          .filter(word => isAlphaNumericOnly.test(word))
                          .filter(word => (word.match(numbersOnly) || []).length % 2 === 1)
                          .filter(word => (word.match(alphaOnly) || []).length % 2 === 0)
                          .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
                           
  return {
    word:   validWords[0],
    length: validWords[0] ? validWords[0].length : -1
  };
}


console.log(findLongestWord("test 5 a0A pass007 ?xy1"));
```